# Cisco restrict MTU size

Tags: cisco, network-core, mtu

Is there an any option in cisco Router we can restrict `MTU` size to something smaller? default is `1514` but for experiment i want to allow `512` only and if packet if bigger than 512 discard them.

Comment: Do you want to restrict packets sent or received?

Comment: A router will normally fragment unless the DF bit is set in the packets.

Comment: Received, but i thought MTU is sent on Interface then why you asking send or receive.. doesn't it work both way?

Comment: The sender is the one which controls the DF bit.

Comment: In short there is no way we can say only and only allow 512 bytes and drop rest????????

Comment: You can deny fragments with an ACL, so you could let the router fragment incoming packets, but deny them outgoing.

Comment: If you use IPv6, the routers will not fragment IPv6 packets, so any MTU lower than 1280 will drop packets larger than that, and that is the minimum IPv6 packet size.

Comment: @Satish - If you just lower the interface MTU to 512 then only frames of that size will get through. However not all devices will let you do that.

Comment: @jwbensley I think lowering MTU means it will break big packet in small chunk but still pass traffic.. In my case i need to stop bigger packet and only allow smaller on... and cisco won't let you do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with policy based routing, although this is an example of filtering any packet bigger than 512 bytes, it does not make your router fragment packets to 512 bytes.

```
ip access-list extended Filter
 permit ip any any

router-map Filter
 match ip address Filter
 match length 1 512
 set interface Null0
```

On the inbound interface:

```
ip policy route-map filter
```

This method will only work on inbound traffic coming in through the interface you have set the policy on

If you want to filter outbound traffic from the router, instead of an interface level command, use the following global command:

ip local policy route-map filter

You can also match only certain traffic by modifying what the access-list matches, or if using the global level command, and you want to filter outbound traffic only on a certain interface, you can do an extra `match <out-bound interface>` command in the route map

Comment: You should also explain that this will cause process routing, which will slow things, and drive up the router CPU utilization.

Comment: Cool! atleast there is an way to do that...! Bravo.

Comment: I have tried your solution but but somehow its sending all packet to `Null0` even smaller packet too.

Comment: Hey Satish, 
Yup, the command `match length 1 512` will match anything between 1 and 512 bytes, adjust the two values to get your min and max desired packet size match. I think I misunderstood your initial request when I wrote that :)

Comment: I am sending `20000` bytes packet but that policy not matching.. something weird going on.. did you test this solution before?

Comment: Sorry my bad.. i get it.. i need to say `match lenght 512 10000`  in order to allow them